# Is there a way to mention a user (blue highlight) without actually pinging them?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there a way to mention a user in Discord without actually pinging them? I wouldn't want something like a role ping because you would have to delete the role, and when newer people view it, it would be seen as @deleted-role.

Also tried unicode and that didn't work. Checked other libraries, and nothing. I found a bot that could do it, but checking it's message.content showed nothing, and D.JS's v12 feature [disableMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/MessageOptions) only inserts a thin unicode character to break the mention, which results in something like `<@id>`, or `<@(really_small_unicode_char)id>` (@\u200b).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, see [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#allowed-mentions-object).

You can do something like this...

```js
message.channel.send("content", {"allowed_mentions": {"parse": []}})
```

and no mentions.

Comment: This causes the user appear as @invalid-user on mobile (at least andriod)! On PC works good.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a message without the ping, then edit the ping in. That way, the user is mentioned but not pinged.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. It's a feature many have wanted, [but it's not implemented](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360039210411--Suggestion-Mentioning-without-pinging)

Comment: I know it's possible, because when I looked at the bot's message, it pinged me without mentioning me, I could click on the mention and my user pop-out appeared.

Answer (score -1):

With python api you can use

```
await message.reply("message", allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(replied_user=False))
```